# how to pass the ajax Post url with paramters to web service?

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, web-services

actually i have webservice running and i want to retrieve the response or output of web service (xml output) and want to show it on some web page. i am trying to give some parameters as input and sending to webservice by AJAX POST and getting some dummy response.. i have problem while sending the parameters with URL. WOULD YOU TELL ME ABOUT THE FORMAT OF AJAX POST PARAMTERS?

`var params="text=text1&target=target1";`

It returns some error value in response, but with the same data i am able to access with the terminal.
**text=text1&target=target1** these paramters are passing as one string not different paramters
I have tried in other way also
`var params='text='+text1+'&target='+target1;`
but it returns nothing in response

What should I set for params value?

Comment: please show your script then only we give solution

Comment: var text1 = document.getElementById("texts").value;
var target1 = document.getElementById("target").value;<
var params="text=text1&target=target1";
[link]var url = "localhost:8080/call/text";
request.onreadystatechange = handleResponse;
request.open("POST", url,true);
request.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
request.setRequestHeader("Content-length",params.length);
request.setRequestHeader("Connection",close);
request.send(params);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't send POST data via url query string.

You will need to either use [`cURL`](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html) from the command line, or use a POST tool like [POSTMAN](http://www.getpostman.com/) to pass form data and the appropriate POST headers.

**Edit**: your tags suggest you're using javascript/ajax.

You can do this [natively with javascript](http://net.tutsplus.com/articles/news/how-to-make-ajax-requests-with-raw-javascript/), but you'd have a significantly easier time using [jQuery's `$.ajax` or `$.post`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/):

```
$.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: "http://myapp.com/someendpoint",
   data: {
      text: "text1",
      target: "target1"
   }
});
```

Comment: thank you Sir....i understood like you cant use xmlHttpRequest for cross site domain

Comment: If the remote resource blocks cross origin headers, then no, it won't work -- it depends entirely on what you're trying to retrieve. If the remote resource doesn't allow CO, then you'll need to proxy the request with either PHP or some form of API proxy.

Comment: actually i have webservice running and i want to retrieve the response or output of web service (xml output) and want to show it on some web page. i am trying to give some parameters as input and sending to webservice by AJAX POST and getting some dummy response.. i have problem while sending the parameters with URL. WOULD YOU TELL ME ABOUT THE FORMAT OF AJAX POST PARAMTERS?

Comment: I AM GETTING THE WRONG RESPONSE but how could i pass appropriate paramters after fetching from web page?